# Eclipse/STS dependency hell

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite, jrebel

I was having few troubles installing new software from Marketplace, so today I decided to start from a fresh install of STS 3.6.4 from spring.io.

I wanted to install some plugins like Subversive, but then I stumbled again into the dependency hell problem.

When I try to install any software, I get an error like the following (this one when trying to install Subversive **in a fresh install with clean workspace**)

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software currently installed: Spring Tool Suite 3.6.4.201503100339-RELEASE-e44 (org.springsource.sts.ide 3.6.4.201503100339-RELEASE-e44)
  Missing requirement: Spring Tool Suite Package 3.6.4.201503100339-RELEASE-e44 (org.springsource.sts.package.feature.group 3.6.4.201503100339-RELEASE-e44) requires 'com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.jira.feature.group 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Spring Tool Suite 3.6.4.201503100339-RELEASE-e44 (org.springsource.sts.ide 3.6.4.201503100339-RELEASE-e44)
    To: org.springsource.sts.package.feature.group [3.6.4.201503100339-RELEASE-e44]
```

I cannot install JRebel on my old STS installation, guess if I can install it, together with the plugins I require, in the new installation!

How can I solve dependency hell in Eclipse/STS? Switching to vanilla Eclipse maybe?

[Edit]
Original error when trying to install JRebel on STS 3.6.1

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software currently installed: SVNKit 1.8.6 Implementation (Optional) 4.1.0.I20140907-1700 (org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.svnkit18.feature.group 4.1.0.I20140907-1700)
  Missing requirement: SVNKit 1.8.6 Implementation (Optional) 4.1.0.I20140907-1700 (org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.svnkit18.feature.group 4.1.0.I20140907-1700) requires 'org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.svnkit18 [4.1.0.I20140907-1700]' but it could not be found
```

Comment: I would like to take a look at the installation issues related to the fresh STS 3.6.4 version. Can you point me at the exact pieces that you tried to install into this vanilla STS 3.6.4 installation?

Comment: From the fresh install of 3.6.4 I simply tried to install Subversive - on an empty workspace

Comment: I tried this again and it seems to work for me. Here is what I did: Dowloaded STS 3.6.4, extracted the archive, started STS. Went to the Marketplace, searched for "subversive", there is one direct entry showing up at the top (Subversive plugin in version 2.0.4). Installed this without issues (selected all features in the upcoming dialog). There was an error about m2e bundles not being found in any repo, but that is unrelated. After installing the subversive I restarted STS and everything seems to be installed just fine. Did you do the exact same thing?

Comment: Hi. Exactly the same (including working on a **clean** workspace) but still error. The "guilty" software is `org.springsource.sts.ide 3.6.4.201503100339-RELEASE-e44` so I couldn't even install Subversive. I'm starting to think that there may be files hidden somewhere (like in the APPDATA folder, which I checked) that the two installations of Eclipe try to use. I can't format my hard drive right now

Comment: @MartinLippert uhm... Now that I think about it **not** exactly the same. Before being able to start STS I must change STS.ini using `-vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_60/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll` or it won't start at all. Could this be...?

Comment: I don't think this is an issue, but I would switch this to a JDK instead of a JRE anyway. Don't think that helps the install issue, but who knows?

Comment: I tried to link STS 3.6.2 (my currently working installation) to JDK (javaw.exe) to see if something ever changes but it will immediately crash after startup.

Comment: Hmmm... When starting with a fresh STS 3.6.4 installation, what exactly goes wrong while trying to install Subversive? Is there anything in the error log showing up? Or just the same error as in the original post above? Sorry for asking so many questions, but since I am not able to reproduce this, it seems to be the only way to figure out what is going wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the update page, did you check "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" ?

Another workaround would be to download eclipse, install Subversive, then STS through updatesite.

Comment: I am sorry but I can't find it (now working on STS 3.6.1). What do you mean by update page? I mainly use Eclipse marketplace

Comment: On this page/wizard : http://theopentutorials.com/totwp331/wp-content/uploads/installing-android-sdk-and-eclipse-adt-plugin_2553/7.android-eclipse-adt-plugin-install.jpg?c3a9c1